# how to remove the old commits history from a specific subdirectory of a github repo?

Tags: git, github, rebase, pull-request, github-flavored-markdown

I'm not expert using git/github, so sorry for my possible uncorrect terms.

Premise:
I'm working on a github repo (a branch of a third party master repo) creating/updating some documentations (markdown files all contained on a subidirectory `path/to/wiki`).

So, working directly on the github web interface (because I need to watch & upgrade .md files looking at the visual effect of web-rendered docs), 
I done a lot of "micro" commits directly on the github page: https://github.com/solyaris/ChatScript/tree/master/wiki

Problem:
Now I finished all my updates and I'd like to do a `pull request` to the external master repo, of work done, possibly avoiding to share the useless "commit story" of tens of commit updates...

**So for each .md  file on the wiki directory, I'd like to send just the FINAL result release of editing (and not all the commit story).**

Maybe this git option is called "rebase" ? Anyway I don't know how exactly achive desired "pruning".

I't possible to delete old commits (just maintaining the final result) contained on a specific directory, or just a specific file, (e.g. this one: https://github.com/solyaris/ChatScript/blob/master/README.md) ?

BTW, there is a way to do that directly on the github page ?

Or I have to clone the repo on my pc, with

```
$ git clone https://github.com/solyaris/ChatScript
$ git ... # commands to delete commit history
$ git push to github
```

Comment: @georgio-robino I've recently created a `chatscript` tag, but this seems to not really be about it specifically so I won't edit it in. But, as I can see you're a contributor and often respond to CS questions on SO, could you please help with tagging questions as they come up? Would be much appreciated :)

Comment: @Matt Fletcher, 
First point: I certainly agree. 
Second point: what I have to do exactly to tagging questions? 
Thanks

Comment: Oh just that if anyone asks a question about chatscript but doesn't add it as a tag, edit the question to include it. Hopefully the tag will stick; I've not added one before so don't know much about it, but I've read about some stack exchange sites removing the tag if it doesn't get a new question each month. Cheers

Comment: Ok! BTW, I think StackOverflow would be perfect for ChatScript even if until now his inventor Bruce Wilcox and the CS community still use Chatbots.org forum: https://www.chatbots.org/ai_zone/viewforum/44/

minor point: `ChatScript` could be better that `chatscript`

Comment: Yeah I'm a member of that too, but haven't posted anything on it. I'll probably be making various changes/PRs to the repo in the future, so I'm sure we'll be in communication. And stackoverflow tags are lowercase I believe!

Answer (score 0):

BTW, maybe I discovered myself a solution (sorry for answering myself).

If I well understand reading this github help doc:

https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/

the master repo owner is able, when merging a pull request on the github web interface, using A "**squash**" flag, that seems to do exactly what I want (to accept updates retaining just a single commit, instead of the full story of commits). That's solve my problem!

That's correct ?

Answer (score -3):

What you want to do is bad practice.  Git is meant to hold all your crazy revisions and publish them others to make use of (to exclude some or to build on top of).  It's up to maintainers if they want to include your craziness in their commit logs, and if they don't then it's as easy as `git pull --squash <remote> <refspec>`

But I will answer your question any way

---

No, that is not what you want to do.  Instead, you should start a new branch on your local repository and just place all the changes onto it in one commit

```
git checkout -b changes-for-pr master
git diff master..branch-with-my-work-so-far -- path/to/subdirectory | git apply
git add .
git commit
```

By the way: GitHub, although wonderful for hosting, is a very poor frontend for Git.  Even Linus Torvalds (creator of Git) bashes on it.

Comment: Sincerely I don't see the "bad practice" in this specific case: avoiding to pull req all micro commits story is, my side, almost a form of courtesy/cleanliness :). 
Anyway, as far as you know, there is a simple way (just using the github web frontend) to do the "squash" you mention, by master node owner (when I'll pull req ?) 
thx

Comment: You should leave your opinion  to yourself. Its very controversial, and doesn't help with answeing the question. I prefer to have comits in my history that represent one logical change each. But sometimes thats not possible - I have to leave the Pc and commit something that is truly messy.. A day later i pick it up, bring it in somewhat usable form, and then I will rewrite the history. there is benefit in having the history cluttered with crap, it only makes tracking down changes that introdued bugs much more difficult and makes blaming files tedious. Same for your opinion about GitHub.